# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi.GPIO'; 'RPi' is not a package

Tags: python, raspberry

tengo un problema con un programa en Python que les muestro la porción de inicio enseguida:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from flask_caching import Cache
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, request, jsonify
import folium
import threading
import simplekml
import time
from time import sleep
import serial
import os #
import binascii
import datetime
import subprocess
import psutil
import platform
import datetime
from geopy.distance import geodesic
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import json
import math
**import RPi.GPIO as GPIO**

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)#Indica que se usarán físicamente los pines como están establecidos en la placa.
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.OUT)#Establece el Pin 12 como salida.
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)#Establece el pin16 XBEE RESET
GPIO.output(16, False)# PI XBEE Reset

#Reset XBee
GPIO.output(16,True)
sleep(0.2)
GPIO.output(16,False)
sleep(1)

#energy PI PICO
GPIO.output(12, False)#PI PICO
sleep(1)#APAGADO
GPIO.output(12,True)
print("Pico Enable")
sleep(2)
```

en el cual tengo un programa en el utilizo los GPIO, resumidamente, el programa lo tengo en una ubicación (~/home/pi/Gateway/gateway/Gps/Rasp/)de mi repositorio de git dentro de mi raspberry, pero al querer ejecutarlo por terminal con python3 Appgood.py o sudo python3 Appgood.py. en esa ubicación me aparece el siguiente error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi.GPIO'; 'RPi' is not a package.
Sin embargo si ejecuto una copia que hice del mismo código en la direccion raiz ~/home/Appgood.py, este me funciona bien. Alguien le ha pasado, me pueden decir como solucionarlo.
De antemano ya reinstale e instalé los gpio varias veces, probé con diferentes versiones de raspbian (10,11) y en todas me sucede lo mismo. Espero me hechen la mano Saludos !

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola Jesus, bienvenido, seguro que voy a decir una estupidez, pero... no debería ser **from RPI import GPIO**?.